# Why do we call STO-nG a basis set?

Tags: computational-chemistry

Why do we call the Hartree Fock basis-set for an atom a "basis set?" In linear algebra, a basis must be linearly independent. Looking at the STO-3G "basis set", the basis functions in this set are not linearly independent.

Let me define the basis set and show why I say they are not linearly independent:

For Hartree Fock with STO-3G basis, to represent carbon you would need the following basis:

**Carbon atom:**
$$ \begin{align*} 
\Phi_{1s}(r) &= d_{11} g_{11}(r) + d_{12} g_{12}(r) + d_{13} g_{13}(r) \\\\[10pt] 
\Phi_{2s}(r) &= d_{21} g_{21}(r) + d_{22} g_{22}(r) + d_{23} g_{23}(r) \\\\[10pt] 
\Phi_{2px}(r) &= d_{31} g_{31}(r) + d_{32} g_{32}(r) + d_{33} g_{33}(r) \\\\[10pt] 
\Phi_{2py}(r) &= d_{41} g_{41}(r) + d_{42} g_{42}(r) + d_{43} g_{43}(r) \\\\[10pt] 
\Phi_{2pz}(r) &= d_{51} g_{51}(r) + d_{52} g_{52}(r) + d_{53} g_{53}(r) 
\end{align*} $$

where above, $d_{ij}$ are coefficients and $g_{ij}$ are gaussians.

And, for Carbon, here is the JSON for STO-3G:

```json
[
  {
    "function_type": "gto",
    "region": "",
    "angular_momentum": 0,
    "exponents": ["0.7161683735E+02", "0.1304509632E+02", "0.3530512160E+01"],
    "coefficients": [
      ["0.1543289673E+00", "0.5353281423E+00", "0.4446345422E+00"]
    ]
  },
  {
    "function_type": "gto",
    "region": "",
    "angular_momentum": [0, 1],
    "exponents": ["0.2941249355E+01", "0.6834830964E+00", "0.2222899159E+00"],
    "coefficients": [
      ["-0.9996722919E-01", "0.3995128261E+00", "0.7001154689E+00"],
      ["0.1559162750E+00", "0.6076837186E+00", "0.3919573931E+00"]
    ]
  }
]
```

To quickly explain this JSON, for Carbon there are two energy levels, 1S and 2S + 2P. Therefore you have two sets of brackets which represents the energy levels. The second set  has one set of exponents and two sets of coefficients. The two coefficient sets are for 2S and 2P orbitals, and because both the 2S and 2P orbitals use the same exponential there is only one set of exponents.

So, looking at this, the basis functions:

$$ \begin{align*} 
\Phi_{2pz}(r) &= \Phi_{2py}(r) = \Phi_{2px}(r) \\\\[10pt]
&=0.1559 e^{-0.29 r^2} + 0.608 e^{-0.68 r^2} + 0.392 e^{-0.22 r^2}
\end{align*} $$

So, these are not linearly independent. Then, why do we call them a basis? Is STO-nG just an improper basis set?

Comment: Atomic orbitals also contains an angular momentum part, or if you use a cartesian representation, a polynomial part, which makes them linearly independent even if they have the same Gaussian exponents for the radial part. For example, you have to multiply the $p_x$ orbital with x, while $p_y$ gets multiplied with y, etc. What you wrote down are not the complete/proper basis functions.

Comment: Oh so the angular term is different for each P orbital? Thanks that does clear it up!

Comment: BTW it should be "carbon" not "Carbon".

Comment: Its also a good idea to check Matter Modeling Exchange for questions like this. [This](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9133/2289) question/answer discusses how you can transform cartesian basis functions to spherical functions and mentions some useful references.

Comment: Do you want to answer or should I delete the question? @HansWurst

Comment: @Frank I have no intention to write more on the matter. But I would recommend to leave it open as is. Deleting questions is generally not a good idea. Even in its current form it can be helpful to other people and in the future someone else or even you yourself could write a proper answer.